# Visual Studio Online and Local Build Host

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

We have visual studio online  professional license and MSDN, we need a local build server as we require third party controls.  Can anyone tell me the licensing on this? Do we need to purchase a local TFS license as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the MSDN subscription account you have is one of the followings, you can download and deploy **one instance** of Team Foundation Server 2015 from [MSDN subscriber download](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/hh442898.aspx) site, and you get **one CAL**(Client Access License) as well.

- Visual Studio Enterprise with MSDN
- Visual Studio Professional with MSDN
- Visual Studio Test Professional with MSDN
- MSDN Platforms

However, for example, if you want to have 2 build servers to associate with VSO, you have to buy another one license for TFS (TFS license includes build service); similarly, if you want to allow 10 users to use the build server, you may need to buy CAL license based on the TFS license you have (for example, Team Foundation Server 2015 purchased in retail channels contains up to five CALs)

Please check the license white paper for the details: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350

Comment: There is no requirement for a VSO user to ever have to **buy** a TFS licence.

Answer (score 3):

No additional software needs to be purchased to setup a build environment with VSO.

If you want to setup a Xaml build controller the easiest way to get that is to download and install but not configure TFS Express which is free and does grant you a license to use the software.  Once that is done you can simply launch the admin console and configure the build controller against your VSO account.

With the new build system you simply download the agent software directly from VSO in your account control panel.  You can find documentation here https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/agents/windows#ManuallydeployabuildagentDownloadandconfiguretheagent

Each account allows you to connect 1 Xaml controller or 1 agent for free.  To connect additional agents you need to purchase more Private Agents you can see details on pricing here https://www.visualstudio.com/features/continuous-integration-vs and here https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/setup/get-more-build-or-load-testing-vs